# Initialize derived class arguments in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
class A {

    int x, y;

public: 
    A(int _x = 0, int _y = 0) : x(_x), y(_y) {
        std::cout << "Constructeur de A \n";
        std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y= " << y << std::endl;
    }

};
class B : A {

    int d; 

public: B(int x, int y, int _d=2) : A(x,y), d(_d) {
    std::cout << "Constructeur de B \n";
    std::cout << "d = " << d<< std::endl;
}


};
```

So i have the above code which does not compile. my ques is why can't i initialize `d` without the need of initializing the `Base` class argument? It's like saying i can't allow the user to only provide a value for `d` only and use base class default arguments (i find it redundant to initialize base class arguments again, would have made sens if i wanted to change default values to something else). the error message does not tell me much `'B': no appropriate default constructor available`.

Comment: It is very confusing to call your member variables the same name as your constructor arguments.

Comment: Seems to compile - https://ideone.com/NDeV0o

Comment: @mathematician1975 I disagree. I don't see the problem.

Comment: weird it doesnt compile in my VS 2015

Comment: @clcto ya it does work, but why cant i do it the way i did

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the `B` constructor? As it stands, this is not a [MCVE]

Comment: Compiles fine in VS2015 for me, even if I construct a `B`.

Comment: @mathematician1975 it's a normal technique to use the same name for member variables as for the constructor arguments which initialize those variables.  I find it preferable to putting "warts" all over the constructor argument names.

Comment: Wild guess here, but perhaps you overlooked that `class B : A` means `class B : private A` and you write some other code assuming public inheritance

Comment: Thanks yall!! the problem was indeed that i forgot about my main, because i was testing many things, i was call `B` with an empty constructor

Comment: @M.M Interesting - I have never seen that before and found it confusing to look at initially.

Comment: @mathematician1975 if you understand what's happening there, you will not find it confusing IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If to remove typos and add a constructor with one parameter of class B then the code is compiled successfully

```
#include <iostream>

class A {

    int x, y;

public: 
    A(int x = 0, int y = 0) : x(x), y(y) {
        std::cout << "Constructeur de A \n";
        std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y= " << y << std::endl;
    }

};

class B : A {

    int d; 

public:
    B( int d ) :d( d ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Constructeur de B( int ) \n";
        std::cout << "d = " << d<< std::endl;
    }        
    B(int x, int y, int d=2) : A(x,y), d(d) 
    {
        std::cout << "Constructeur de B( int, int, int ) \n";
        std::cout << "d = " << d<< std::endl;
    }
};    

int main()
{
    B b( 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Constructeur de A 
x = 0, y= 0
Constructeur de B( int ) 
d = 1
```

Class A has the default constructor. Its only explicitly defined constructor is the default constructor of the class.

The code also compiles using the on-line MS C++ compiler.

As for this error message

> 'B': no appropriate default constructor available

then class B indeed has no default constructor. But you could for example redefine its constructor the following way

```
    B( int d = 0 ) :d( d ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Constructeur de B( int ) \n";
        std::cout << "d = " << d<< std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles fine.
If you would like to call `B`'s constructor with only `d` given, you should write a constructor for it:

```
public: B(int d) :d(d){...}
```

And call the constructor with `B b(1);` for example. However your compiler said:

> 'B': no appropriate default constructor available

Therefore you must have called the constructor for `B` like this: `B b;` which is the same as `B b = B()` (explicit). It calls the default constructor which is auto generated by the compiler if no constructors are given. You have given one, so you can write the default constructor or, more elegantly, force the compiler to generate it (C++11):

```
B() = default;
```

If you used `B` in a container, the container may call the default constructor for `B`.

You do not have to do the same with `A`, since it already has a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided default arguments in `B` constructor, C++ won't guess them from how you use them. Either give them default values:

```
B(int x = 0, int y = 0, int _d = 0): A(x, y), d(_d) {
```

or provide another, real default constructor:

```
B(int _d = 0): A() /*will use A(x=0,y=0)*/, d(_d) {
```